# Class method that uses setTimeout() and setInterval() works unexpectedly on repeated calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, settimeout, setinterval

*tldr: On the first go round lose() works fine but on successive calls, as the player restarts and loses again, retry() is called immediately and msgRepeater() only displays if the user chooses to exit.*

When the user loses this node.js game, the class method lose() is called.

lose() first runs another method, msgRepeater(), that repeats a message at intervals for a set period.

Then lose() runs  another method, retry(), to prompt the user to restart or exit the game (this runs after a setTimeout() within retry() to allow msgRepeater() to complete first).

On the first go round this works fine but on successive calls, as the player restarts and loses again, retry() is called immediately and the message is only repeated if the user chooses to exit (tho not for as long and accumulated by the number of replays).

Do I have a problem in my approach to setInterval and/or setTimeout? I am stuck and any resolutions would be massively appreciated!

```
//***Retry***
retry() {
    const retry = () => {
      while(this.gameOver && !this.exit) {
        let input = prompt('Play Again? y/n: ');
        if(input==='y') {
          this.play();
        }
        else if(input==='n') {
          this.exit=true;
        }
        else {
          console.log(
            'I don\'t understand,\ndo you want to play again? y/n: '
          )
        };
      }
    }
    setTimeout(retry, 5000);
  };

  //***Repeated Message***
  msgRepeater(text) {
    const newMsg = () => console.log(text);
    const msgInterval = setInterval(newMsg, 400);
    const endMsgInterval = () => {
      clearInterval(msgInterval); 
    }
    setTimeout(endMsgInterval, 4000);
  }

  //***Lose***
  lose() {
    this.msgRepeater('You Lose!');
    this.retry();
  }
```

Comment: you never clear your `retry` timeout or your `endMsgInterval` timeout. Assign each to a variable, and clear the `retry` in the `y` or `n` condition blocks, and clear `endMsgInterval` inside itself.

Comment: I tried clearing the timeouts in this normal way but in Node that just doesn't seem to work. I dug a bit further and I think I'm accurate in saying that using timeouts in Node returns an object of properties rather than just the usual number that gets zeroed by clearTimeout. What I finally got to work was clearing the timeout and reassigning it's variable to an empty object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in is in trying to clear a timeout in Node (where I believe a timeout returns an object of properties rather than just an incremental number as usual). A solution I have found is clearing the timeout in the usual way and then reassigning the timeout variable to an empty object. It works though it might be a bit messy and I would certainly be interested in other solutions.

```
const callback = () => {
  //body of function here
  clearTimeout(myTimeout); 
  myTimeout = {};
}
const myTimeout = setTimeout(callback,1000);
```